# Facing an error while building. Gradle may be corrupt

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting the following error:

```
    Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: So have you tried any of these suggestions?

Comment: i have killed all java processes and restart but didn't work, can you tell how to kill gradle deamons?

Comment: "./gradlew --stop" Also try cleaning caches

Comment: where to run this command?

Comment: On the terminal, inside your project's directory.

Answer (score 16):

Try this solution

1.delete {project dir}/.gradle/1.9

2.Sync Project with Gradle File

**

### OR

**

If it doesn't work then try for this solution:

- Clone  project to a new folder
- Remove .gradle, .idea folders
- Add as a new project (File > Open > [new folder])

Comment: Glad to help, if it resolved your issue then mark answer as accepted, so  it will help others by putting for extra google keystrokes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Same Here... follow work for me

1. After giving error"Re-download dependencies etc..." click on **android monitor** at bottom end
2. Click on "**Please configure android SDK**"
3. Click on **Project** at Left Side Menu
4. Give another **Build Version and Build Version Name**
5. Copy ***

> build.gradle code from another successful project and paste"replace"
>   all in this error'd gradle and click sync

---

6. Gradle will start built... Successfully but **time consumed**

Comment: What do you mean by **"please configure android sdk"**?